# Check value in array without $in

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Let's say I have the following documents:

```
{
  title: 'Some title',
  items: [1,5,9,4]
}

{
  title: 'Some title',
  items: [5,7]
}

{
   title: 'Some title',
   items: [1,2]
}
```

I need to get a documents where items have 5. So I make the following query in mongoose:

```
Model.find({items: {$in: [5]}}, function (err, docs) {
   // docs.length == 2
});
```

And I'm getting it. But I've found that if I make the follows query then I get the same:

```
Model.find({items: 5}, function (err, docs){
   // docs.length == 2
});
```

Is is correct to use the second approach to find docs in my case?

Comment: $in is for if you have more than one value to match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$in` when you want to find the docs where `items` contains any one of a set of values; if you want the docs where `items` contains a specific value, use a simple query object like `{items: 5}`.

So while, as you found, you can use `$in` to match against a single value, it's more naturally expressed as `Model.find({items: 5}, ...);`